# How to have a @PATCH annotation for JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jax-rs

JAX-RS has annotations for HTTP verbs such as `GET` (`@GET`) and `POST` (`@POST`) but there is no `@PATCH` annotation. How can I have an annotation for the `PATCH` HTTP verb?

Something like the following:

```java
@PATCH
public Response someCode() {
    // Code to handle the request
}
```

Comment: JAX-RS 2.1 supports [`@PATCH`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/PATCH.html) out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I got answer [here](http://brianoneill.blogspot.in/2011/11/patch-methods-on-jax-rs.html).

One will just have to define a custom Patch annotation, what that means is that you will have to write a **PATCH.java** file with following code:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("PATCH")
public @interface PATCH {
}
```

**Import** the **package containing PATCH.java** and then you can use it like other HTTP method annotations:

```
@PATCH
@Path("/data/{keyspace}")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public void patchRow(@PathParam("keyspace") String keyspace, String body) 
throws Exception
```

I used this @PATCH to send some JSON to my REST service.

Comment: I used this @PATCH to send some JSON to my REST service and it worked like a charm. You can't do this using GET request, so there is no doubt it getting default to GET request.

Comment: @LutzHorn I am using this `@PATCH` 'alongside' `@GET` using the same `@Path` with no troubles so far, using Jersey 1.17.1

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. Jersey treats method annotated with `@PATCH` as resource locator method. What I possibly missed?

Comment: How is PATCH support still not integrated in `javax.ws.rs`? I mean, really.

Comment: @Jorn I am amazed too.

Comment: @VishalDevgire, can you publish some more code if possible ?

Comment: JAX-RS 2.1 supports `@PATCH` out-of-the-box :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe the first non milestone release was in August. My boss doesn't want to use it because of this. I don't either. Hopefully he'll like this slick workaround and let me keep my patches. arrr!

Comment: @patryk I have the same problem, how did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 27):

### Using JAX-RS 2.1?

[JAX-RS 2.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_1-final-eval-spec/jaxrs-2_1-final-spec.pdf) added [`@PATCH`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/PATCH.html) to the list of supported HTTP methods.

### Using Swagger?

When using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to document a REST API, you could use the existing [`@PATCH`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/PATCH.java) annotation defined in the `io.swagger.jaxrs` package.

### Using Jersey and Dropwizard?

[Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io) defines a [`@PATCH`](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.0/dropwizard-jersey/apidocs/io/dropwizard/jersey/PATCH.html) annotation in the `io.dropwizard.jersey` package.

### Write your own

If the above mentioned approaches don't work for you, you can write your own `@PATCH` annotation:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("PATCH")
public @interface PATCH { }
```

The [`@HttpMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HttpMethod.html) annotation is used to associate the name of a HTTP method with an annotation, creating a what the JAX-RS specification calls *resource method designator*.

Your own `@PATCH` annotation should [work fine](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/pull/1679) in Swagger.

Answer (score 5):

In Jersey this will work just fine, but when using Jersey Client to test your resource class, you will get exceptions:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
```

There is a workaround for this, by setting client property

```
HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND
```

But wait, then you will end up with the following exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method PATCH doesn't support output
```

So there is no other way than changing to the Apache HTTP client library, using Jersey version 2.10, its easy to configure to use Apache HTTP client, you only need to override the client config method in your test class that extends `JerseyTest`.

```java
@Override
protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
  config.register(CustomJacksonJsonProvider.class);
  ConnectorProvider connectorProvider = new ApacheConnectorProvider();
  config.connectorProvider(connectorProvider);
}
```

And you need to also add another Maven dependency, `jersey-apache-connector` and `jersey-test-framework-provider-external`, see [Jersey doc](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS API 2.0.1 doesn't have PATCH. But, looking at JAX-RS API 2.2-SNAPSHOT code, PATCH is now included. The code is:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod(HttpMethod.PATCH)
@Documented
public @interface PATCH {
}
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/blob/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/PATCH.java).

You might use the same codes for remedy until 2.2 is out. For HttpMethod.PATCH, just replace it with "PATCH".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CXF 3.1.2 or later ([source](https://github.com/apache/cxf/commit/200b2825439a5ac42d0f848a53ad33441befe62c)), you can use `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.PATCH`.

Answer (score -1):

This is my implementation of PATCH with jax-rs 2.2

**Person class**

```
public class Person {


    private Integer id;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String surname;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Person REST API**

```
/**
 * see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902 for further explanations
 */
@PATCH
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id}")
public void modify(@PathParam("id") int id,
                   JsonArray input) {
    personDB.update(id, input);
}
```

**PersonDB**

```
public void update(int id, final JsonArray input) {

    final Person person = people.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getId() == id)
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);

    final JsonObject source; // json object person representation

    try (JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(Json.createValue(JsonbBuilder.create().toJson(person)).getString()))) {
        source = jsonReader.readObject();
    }

    final JsonObject output; // apply update to source object
    try {
        output = Json.createPatch(input).apply(source);
    } catch (JsonException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
    }

    try (final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create()) { // apply updates to final object
        final Person target = jsonb.fromJson(output.toString(), Person.class);
        person.setName(target.getName());
        person.setSurname(target.getSurname());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }
}
```

Test the API:

```
PATCH /person/{id}
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/name",
        "value": "John"
    }
]
```

[Here](https://github.com/fstarred/java-ee-collections) you can find the project with full example

See also [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902%20for%20further%20explanations) for further explanations