# How to use PATCH method in CXF Client

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, cxf, http-patch

I was trying to call a API with PATCH method using CXF (Version 3.1.3) client.

Tried following the steps specified in below threads but not able resolve.
Only getting URLConnectionHttpConduit instead of AsyncHttpConduit

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/asynchronous-client-http-transport.html

[How to use PATCH method in CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067687/how-to-use-patch-method-in-cxf)

[Verifying CXF HttpAsyncClient use of use.async.http.conduit contextual property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277043/verifying-cxf-httpasyncclient-use-of-use-async-http-conduit-contextual-property)

Here is the code snippet:

```
    Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus();
    // insist on the async connector to use PATCH.
    bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC,  
AsyncHTTPConduitFactory.UseAsyncPolicy.ALWAYS);
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(request.getRestURL());
   WebClient.getConfig(webClient).getBus().setProperty
     (AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, AsyncHTTPConduitFactory.UseAsyncPolicy.ALWAYS);
   WebClient.getConfig(webClient).getRequestContext()
       .put(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, AsyncHTTPConduitFactory.
       UseAsyncPolicy.ALWAYS);
    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit)WebClient.getConfig(webClient)
                           .getConduit();
    System.out.println(conduit.getClass().getName());

    Response response = webClient.invoke(request.getMethod(), null);
    System.out.println("service response = "+ response);
```

I even tried using X-HTTP-Method-Override=PATCH header with a POST request,

Other side service is implemented using RestEasy and  look's like not honoring X-HTTP-Method-Override header.

Can you please help me finding the issue.

Comment: Are you using right version of jar? post version of jar and check the source code of the class if you have it.

Comment: Did you set the property use.async.http.conduit as per SE question you quoted in the post and added dependency properly?

Comment: yes, As I already mentioned I am setting the property AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC ( use.async.http.conduit) 

CXF Jar versions 3.1.3, Added the hc jar dependency as well.

Comment: I also tried setting the property value different values like  TRUE and ALWAYS

  bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC,  
AsyncHTTPConduitFactory.UseAsyncPolicy.ALWAYS);

or

  bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC,  
Boolean.TRUE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we got similar problem, we have used `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` and it works fine. Below is the sample code for your reference:

```
IOReactorConfig ioReactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom().setIoThreadCount(10).build();
ConnectingIOReactor ioReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(ioReactorConfig);
PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(ioReactor);
cm.setMaxTotal(100);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);

RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(30000)
                .setSocketTimeout(30000).build();

CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .setConnectionManagerShared(false)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();
httpclient.start();

HttpPatch httpReq = new HttpPatch(url);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpReq.setEntity(entity);

Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(httpReq, context, null);
HttpResponse httpResponse = future.get();
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String responseText = responseEntity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity) : null;
```

You can refer to the [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/nio/client/CloseableHttpAsyncClient.html) for any more details.